# PayPal Sandbox Testing Multi-Vendor Commission Fee Not Found

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was playing with PayPal Sandbox to integrate to our platform.
This is what my body looks like when creating order.
Order was approved and captured successfully, but commission fees don't come to my sandbox account.
Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "ORDER1",
      "payee": {
        "merchant_id": "YKSAWY4EFUQ9N",
        "email_address": "markz@example.com"
      },
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "2000.00"
      },
      "payment_instruction": {
        "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
        "platform_fees": [
          {
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "200.00"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "sb-3zuuc16985762@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "VZBJPJUECRLUY"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "reference_id": "ORDER2",
      "payee": {
        "merchant_id": "P7P8DG5Z9YF54",
        "email_address": "stevejobs@example.com"
      },
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "1000.00"
      },
      "payment_instruction": {
        "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
        "platform_fees": [
          {
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100.00"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "sb-3zuuc16985762@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "VZBJPJUECRLUY"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

platform_fees are not credited to a PayPal account, ever. In production, they will be deposited to the confirmed bank account associated with the account. The only place you will see them is in a [financial detail report.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/reports/financial-detailed/)

Also, in order to use platform_fees the receiver of the transaction must first be onboarded with a `third_party_details` set to `PARTNER_FEE` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/#definition-third_party_details